# Multilanguage Taxonomy 

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am getting lost with the multilanguage Taxonomy management in drupal 7.

The english version of the site is build so that a product is taged with a unique term, that may belong to a parent term. So Product Type > Parent type > Sub type. 
The product can be reach at a URL that is build according to their catergory so : 
Product Type/Parent type/Sub type/Product-name

All of this is working fine but i now need to add more languages to that site. So here is what i have done so far:

1- Enabled Taxonomy translation Module with all it s dependencies.

2- Activating  "Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated" for my vocabulary (Product Type)

3- Added translation to each Product type terms

Now i have 2 problems.

First all the translated terms are shown in the Term reference drop down in node creation and translation (as i plan on having 5 languages it s going to be very confusing), and this happens even when i am translating a node (I was expecting the field to be prfield with the corresponding translation from the term of the main node, otherwise what s the point of translating terms ?)

Second the Menu path doesn't display the translated terms, when i switch language i always get : node/nid even though i defined the following pattern for the url

```
[node:field-product-category:i18n-vocabulary:name]/[node:field-product-category:root:i18n-name]/[node:title]
```

**EDIT:**
I tried using "Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized." for my vocabulary, which would make more sense as i don't want all translated terms to show in the term reference drop down in node creation and translation. Though now it seems even worst as i after switching to french, the term attached to that node doesn't seem to translate at all even though i have already translated it.

**EDIT2** So far i think my best option is to create one vocabulary per language and one content type for each language. Any better idea ?
PS i am not using Views at all

Is there anyway to make all of this work as it was intended ?

Comment: I had some problem like you, finally I create 2 vocabulary , each for one languages, but somethimes had a error and show worng languages terms  :(