# Why is an empty field on translated taxonomy term showing default language value?

Tags: views, entities, i18n-l10n

I have a list of translated taxonomy terms (title, description, link, image). Only some of the translated terms have a value in the link field. Set up as Entity translation

My view pulls all fields and displays the default language link when no value is present on the translated term. I actually do not want to see the default link. I'd like that field to remain empty if it does not exist on the translated term.

I've deselected language fall back in the language config and set the view to hide the field if empty, but I am still showing the default language field value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Checking to see if anyone might have feedback on this??

Comment: I think you could filter results based on field language if you Implemented field translation.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/how-to-show-translated-taxonomy-terms-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

You may get it to work by using the [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module, which extends the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module with multilingual support for [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

To make Views results correspond to the language switcher, add a filter for **Content Translation: User's Current Language**, which is the language that an authenticated user has set in the user settings (it is NOT the same as the current browser language or the site language).

If no option for the **User's Current Language** is available in the filter criteria form, then verify your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: The order should be **URL, Default, User** and not something like **Default, URL, User** (as mentioned also in https://www.drupal.org/node/1701854#comment-6279474).

**Note**: True, the [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module only has a **DEV** / **Alfa** version for D7, but right now there are [over 37K users using this version](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/i18nviews). Therefor I think "DEV" is not a valid release qualifier for that version anymore, because *+37K users can't be wrong*, right?